How to open server using Dash Python in Eclipse on Windows
I am trying to create a dashboard using Dash. I'm struggling to get this code running.
# importing required libraries

import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
#from dash import dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas_datareader as web

app = dash.Dash()
app.title = "Stock Visualisation"
 
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1("Stock Visualisation Dashboard"),
    html.H4("Please enter the stock name"),
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='AAPL', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='output-graph')
])


# callback Decorator 
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-graph', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
)
def update_graph(input_data):
    start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
 
    try:
        df = web.DataReader(input_data, 'yahoo', start, end)
 
        graph = dcc.Graph(id ="example", figure ={
            'data':[{'x':df.index, 'y':df.Close, 'type':'line', 'name':input_data}],
            'layout':{
                'title':input_data
            }
        })
 
    except:
        graph = html.Div("Error retrieving stock data.")
 
    return graph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port = 8080)

I'm not getting an error but still unable to open the link. What can I try to fix it?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.
